# Make checked checkbox to Unchecked

Tags: jquery

I unable to make checked checkbox to unchecked checkbox.

```
$("#search_list").find('.mselect input:checked').each(function(index, ele) {
            var prodId = $(this).val();
            console.log($(this));
            //if($(this).is(':checked')){
            //if($(this).length) {
                $(productList).each(function(key, value) {
                    console.log("ohh"+value);
                    if(prodId == value){
                        $(this).prop('checked', false);
                        console.log($(this));
                        console.log("unchedk"+value);
                    }
                });
            //}
        });
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: You should include the HTML for the controls you are trying to change, as well as any error messages you can see in the browser console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context `$(this)` refers to current element/property of `productList`. Assign `$(this)` of checkbox to a variable like (commented code removed)

```
$("#search_list").find('.mselect input:checked').each(function(index, ele) {

    var $checkbox = $(this), // now use $checkbox instead of $(this) in the next loop 
                             // (the dollar sign is to indicate that the variable is alreay a jQuery object).
        prodId = $(this).val();

    $(productList).each(function(key, value) {

        if (prodId == value) {
            $checkbox.prop('checked', false);
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: @Andreas, you are absolutely right. I suppose the convention I learned has a flaw.

Comment: Yes `$this` is not referring to check box. it referring to array of productList.

Comment: Yes, I understand my mistake. Thanks.